# Alarm Manager | Incorrectly Trigerred when time updated

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am experimenting with using Alarm Manager for repeated notification.

I have an activity which opens with the time picker and the user can either go with the app default time or custom pick a time and set notification. Once done, the following code runs to set an alarm trigger.

```
        notificationTime = new Session(context).getNotificationTime();
        if(notificationTime == null){
            // Set App default time (16:30)
            notificationTime = new NotificationTime();
        }
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, notificationTime.hours);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, notificationTime.minutes);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }else{
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
```

The alarm trigger calls the NotificationReceiver BrodcastReceiver where I generate a notification

```
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        String name = "Reminder";
        String id = "Reminder"; // The user-visible name of the channel.
        String description = "Reminder"; // The user-visible description of the channel.

        Intent repeatingIntent = new Intent(context, RepeatingActivity.class);
            repeatingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, repeatingIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Log.d("My Log", "Broadcast Received");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
                mChannel.setDescription(description);
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, id);

            builder.setContentTitle("Custom Alarm")  // required
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder) // required
                    .setContentText("Reminder")  // required
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setTicker("Custom Alarm")
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        }else{
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

            builder.setContentTitle("Custom Alarm")                           // required
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder) // required
                    .setContentText("Reminder")  // required
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setTicker("Custom Alarm")
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        }
        Log.d("My Log", "Notification Triggered");
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(100, notification);
```

This setup works perfectly fine except for the following scenario:
1. Let us say I set the notification to be triggered at 13:00

2. The notification triggers as expected
3. Now within a few minutes minutes, if I go to the app and set the notification time to say 20:00
4. I get a notification immediately (i.e. as soon as i change the time to 20:00 and save the notification time). The logs "Broadcast Received" and "Notification Triggered" are logged as well in the LogCat section.

What could be causing this behavior? How do I avoid this unexpected notification but instead trigger it at the updated time only.

I tried to cancel the AlarmManager every time the notification time is update. Still not functional as expected.

[Update 1]: I uninstalled the app and ran it again. As soon as I set the time and save the notification, I got the App notification immediately. (The time was set to 15 hours ahead from the current time)

Answer (score 0):

You can trivially fix this by deduping the alarm.  Write the time you last handled the alarm to shared preference.  When you're woken up, check that preference.  If its less than a day, return and do not process this alarm.

Comment: This solution does not work out. There wasn't any alarm event triggered by Alarm Manager at the time set.